# woocommerce set billing first name

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to find a woocommerce method that will allow me to set the billing and or shipping first name.

The customer class will allow me to set some fields but not first_name.  Anyone know if a method exists or do I need to just update the wp_usermeta table directly using `billing_first_name`.

Here is an example of what doesn't work:

```
global $woocommerce;

$user_first_name = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'first_name', true );

if( !empty( $woocommerce->customer->get_billing_first_name() ) ) {

    $woocommerce->customer->set_billing_first_name($user_first_name); // a set_billing_first_name method doesn't exist

}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! It would help a lot if you posted some code, showing how you are doing it now, and/or how you want to do it in the future. What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Customer in woocommerce is nothing but a Wordpress user. If you look at `WC_Checkout->process_checkout()` is creates a new user and then sets `billing_first_name` as `first_name`.
So  to update the `billing_first_name` update the `first_name` using [update_user_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thats what I ended up doing and it works fine, thanks!